# WSO2 Identity Server: apis to get user info by SAML token?

Tags: node.js, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

We are testing out securing a web application with Identity Server using SAML SSO. The general web security works fine. However, this application also has a web sockets interface it consumes from, in a node.js application. We would like to apply some role based security on the node.js sockets application. What we need is a way to retrieve user information from Identity Server from the node.js app using web services. We can get to all of the cookie based session data, like the SAML token. Is there a way to use the SAML token to make an API call to Identity Server to get role info and attribute values ?

Answer (score 0):

`With the SAML token you can get the attribute values you needed. 
Under the Service Provider registration >> Claim Config 
Select the claims you need 
Under Inbound Authentication Configuration >> SAML2 Web SSO Configuration 
Enable Enable Attribute Profile 
Enable Include Attributes in the Response Always 
With these configurations you can get all attributes with SAML token itself`